# Undefined method 'transactions' for array when running db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am trying to seed my database with some values. Types User, Account, and Transaction are ActiveRecord objects. Two users are created successfully and two accounts on those users are created successfully. When I try to do the same thing in the second block, it tells me `NoMethodError: undefined method 'transactions' for #<Array:0x0000000734d198>`, even though a puts inside the second block shows that account is in fact a #.

```
require 'securerandom'

Account.destroy_all
Branch.destroy_all
Terminal.destroy_all
Transaction.destroy_all
User.destroy_all


users = User.create!([
                         {
                             :name => 'Bob Rob',
                             :email => 'br@gmail.com'
                         }, {
                             :name => 'Frank Krawlin',
                             :email => 'krawlin@gmail.com'
                         }
                     ])

puts users

accounts = []
users.each do |user|
  accounts << user.accounts.create!([{:account_type => 'SAVINGS'}])
end

puts accounts

transactions = []
accounts.each do |account|
  transactions << account.transactions.create!([{:transaction_type => 'WITHDRAWAL', :amount => 500, :expires_at => Time.now + 1.day, :fulfilled => false}])
end

puts transactions

branches = Branch.create!([{:address => '215 Oxford St W, Toronto, ON'}])

terminals = []
branches.each do |branch|
  rand(1..4).times do
    terminals << branch.terminals.create!([{:token => SecureRandom.uuid}])
  end
end
```

Here is the account.rb file where transactions is defined as a has_many relationship:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transactions

  validates :account_type, inclusion: {in: %w(CHEQUING SAVINGS),
                                       message: "%{value} is not a valid account type"}

  before_validation :correct_case

  protected
  def correct_case
    self.account_type.upcase!
  end
end
```

I have no idea what is going on. transactions is definitely defined as has_many on Account. What is causing this error? I am very new to ruby.

Comment: Would you mind to post how have you populated `users` and `accounts`?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida I tried creating each user individually, but they were never a problem. I debugged the output and the users were created just fine. The accounts are created without issue as well. It's the transactions that are giving me the problem.

Comment: This is not easy to reproduce here, then I'll ask you to do some tests. Fisrt, would you please try doing `account.transaction.create!` (singular)?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida It still says NoMethodError, only this time it says NoMethodError: undefined method `transaction' for #<Array:0x000000073d8dd8>. I have even tried swapping the line out with Transaction.create! and passing account.id but then I get NoMethodError: undefined method 'id' for #<Array:0x0000000724c960>.

Comment: Insert a `puts account.class` right after `accounts.each do |account|` and tell me what is the result, please.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida I just tried that and ruby thinks that it's an Array. Using puts on accounts before calling each, however, shows an array with 2 accounts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129125/discussion-between-ed-de-almeida-and-canadait).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrote

```
accounts << user.accounts.create!([{:account_type => 'SAVINGS'}])
```

above, you created not a single account, but an array with a single account. Then, when you say

```
transactions << account.transactions.create!([{:transaction_type => 'WITHDRAWAL', :amount => 500, :expires_at => Time.now + 1.day, :fulfilled => false}])
```

rails thinks you are trying to use a method `#transactions` from an array, which obviously can't be done, since array has no such method.